# Monodevelop F# bindings failed to add

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop

Used local and online repository to add F# bindings - same error.

Monodevelop : 2.4.2.1

gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32

MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding_2.4

windows OS

Error stack :

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: target of an invocation throws an exception. ---> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that other memory is corrupt.
       в Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration()
       в Gtk.Application.RunIteration()
       в Mono.Addins.Gui.InstallMonitor.WaitForCompleted()
       в Mono.Addins.Gui.AddinInstallDialog.Install()
       в Mono.Addins.Gui.AddinInstallDialog.OnPageChanged()
       в Mono.Addins.Gui.AddinInstallDialog.OnNextPage(Object sender, EventArgs e)

       --- end of internal stack ---

       в System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
       в System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
       в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
       в System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       в GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB(Object o, ClosureInvokedArgs args)
       в GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke(ClosureInvokedArgs args)
       в GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)
```

maybe I need to try monodevelop from trunk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this error when installing F# for MonoDevelop on Windows. Unfortunately, this is a [reported bug](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-devel-list/2010-October/000321.html) in MonoDevelop on Windows. A workaround is to copy the assemblies to the MonoDevelop installation directory by hand.

I added some information to the [project homepage](http://functional-variations.net/monodevelop/). (See "Installing F# for MonoDevelop on Windows").